# Why Hibernate validation with Spring data rest happens after @HandleAfteSave is published?

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-rest

I am trying to perform some operation in Spring data events `@HandleBeforeCreate`/ `@HandleBeforeSave`. Looks like with Spring data rest repository, hibernate validation (validation added with annotations like `@NotBlank`) happens after executing methods which are annotated with `@HandleBeforeCreate`/`@HandleBeforeSave` and if validations fail, it rollbacks the original transaction.
My question is why the validations happen before committing, shouldn’t it happen before even executing the `save()` method?

Comment: Validation is done by hibernate, so it will trigger only when Hibernate is being called. That is after the callbacks have been handled, after that control is handed to hibernate.

Comment: Thanks fir your reply but my question is why hibernate is doing like this? first it's saving and if validation fails, it rolling it back? Instead of hibernate validation, if I use spring Validator, it can be register to invoke "beforeCreate" or "beforeSave". Is it possible to achieve same with hibernate?

Comment: As stated Hibernate isn't doing this Spring Data is doing that. It needs to invoke those callbacks BEFORE it calls hibernate. After that hibernate does the validation. Spring Validation will only work on web requests or when explicitly enabled for method validation.

Comment: Any idea why spring has done this? I mean what are their thought process behind adding validation at the time of committing? Is is possible to change this order(validate first and proceed if only validation passes)?

Comment: What has Spring to do with validation... Hibernate (NOT Spring) is doing the validation. There is simply no other way... The validation is part of the creation of the entity... If that would be done first calls to the `beforeCreate` and `beforeSave` would be pretty useless as the entity would already have been saved.

Comment: I think I could not make the question clear. What I'm sating is that, let hibernate validate the entity first, invoke the `beforeCreate ` only if validation  was successful or if this not possible, let hibernate validate after 'beforeCreare' but before 'afterCreate' event.In this way data is not saved and we get to know the validation result before saving data to db.

Comment: Hibernate isn't involved in invoking the `beforeCreate`, Spring Data is. That is Spring Data behavior. And as stated validation is part of persisting/updating an entity it isn't something you invoke yourself. The same would happen if you call `EntityManager.persist` (it would also validate the entity it is bound to the storing of the entity).